# MS Graph API not returning DriveItem Thumbnails correctly

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I have a list of recent and shared DriveItems I need thumbnails for.  First, is there a way to pass a list of DriveItem ids to get the thumbnails in a single call?

All of the DriveItems are pretty basic, all Excel or Word, and they have thumbnails in OneDrive but when I ask for the thumbnails, the large majority return without a thumbnailSet.  The ones that do are all invalid urls with a height and width of -1.  Using the call below:

```
https://.../v1.0/me/drive/items/{driveItemId}/thumbnails
```

Answer (score 0):

For making one call and returning multiple thumbnails:

```
https://.../v1.0/me/drive/items/{item-id}/children?select=id,name&expand=thumbnails(select=large)
```

Personally, I'm having trouble returning thumbnails of certain document types (e.g. Excel spreadsheets), whereas the document and photo thumbnails return without issue. Thus, I'm not sure about the second part of your question.

[OneDrive thumbnail docs](https://dev.onedrive.com/items/thumbnails.htm)

Comment: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/item_list_thumbnails  if you look at the bottom under Remarks, it looks like your calls won't work, although it's hard to tell.  But I tried the /recent?expand=thumbnails and that always returns an empty thumbnails array.

Comment: Have to add a $ to make it work: https://.../v1.0/me/drive/items/{item-id}/children?select=id,name&$expand=thumbnails